# How to fire A-FRAME collision event when two boxes intersect each other?

Tags: aframe

I am trying to detect collision of two boxes in A-FRAME v. 0.5.0. I use raycaster example:
https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/components/raycaster.html#whitelisting-entities-to-test-for-intersection

but for me it only works with cursor intersecting one of the meshes.
As it is written, raycaster detects when line created from a starting point to a certain direction intersects desired mesh (here  marked with a collidable class). It appears that start of this collision-detecting line is somehow set on the camera or on a cursor but not on one of the boxes. How to reassign this starting point?

Before initializing scene I added component:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('collider-check', {
dependencies: ['raycaster'],
init: function () {
    console.log("we have component");
this.el.addEventListener('raycaster-intersected', function () {
    console.log('Player hit something!');
});
},
});
```

and then A-FRAME entities

```
    <a-entity id="player" collider-check >
      <a-entity id="rc" 
        raycaster="objects: .collidable" 
        geometry="primitive: box; width: 0.5; height: 4; depth: 0.5" 
        material="shader: flat; color:gray" 
        position="0 -0.9 0" 
        rotation="90 0 0" ></a-entity>
    </a-entity>

    <a-entity id="inmotion" class="collidable" 
        geometry="primitive: box; width: 0.5; height: 4; depth: 0.5" 
        position="1 0 0"
        material="shader: flat; color: #00CCDD">
        <a-animation id="canim"
          attribute="position" 
            dur="2000"
            from ="-2 -1 0"
            to="2 0 0.5"
            fill="forwards"
            direction="alternate"
            repeat="indefinite">

        </a-animation>
    </a-entity>
```

Here is jsfiddle with the example;
https://jsfiddle.net/Suiseki/9ggs6x4m/2/

Answer (score 4):

Using the raycaster is one way to check for collisions in 3D space, but it's best if one of those shapes is a ray/line. If you have two 3D objects, it's easier to use bounding box or bounding sphere collisions, without a raycaster. Here are example implementations of each:

- [aabb-collider](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/v0.5.0/examples/showcase/tracked-controls/components/aabb-collider.js)
- [sphere-collider](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/blob/v3.3.4/src/misc/sphere-collider.js)

Both will file `hit` events on the elements when they collide. [Example usage](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/blob/master/examples/vive/index.html), for a slightly different case.